# How can I forcefully merge one git branch into another

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a git repository "ui" which has two branches - master and tip.

Over time master and tip drifted apart, so what I did is - on branch master

`git reset --hard tip`

After this when I did `git diff tip` no differences were shown by git.

Now, I changed one file in master branch - pom.xml which is a maven file.
I changed the version in the pom.xml on master.

Now, when I do a `git diff tip` I see the difference in master and tip.

I committed this and pushed to master.

Now, I checked out tip `git checkout tip`
I did a `git diff master` and the difference between the pom.xml on master and tip was visible.

I changed a controller (source code) file on tip, committed it and pushed to tip. When I did a `git diff` two changes were visible - 1. pom.xml 2. code change.

Now, I checked out master and executed the following command -
`git merge -X theirs tip`
This merged the controller file but not the pom.xml and when I do a `git diff tip` this again shows the diff in the pom.xml file.

What is the behavior of the merge command? How can I force git to merge the pom.xml as well?

Comment: Unclear what you expect. When you are on the `master` branch, `git merge tip` has _no effect on tip_. And nothing can change that. Perhaps it would help you to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that saying `git diff` between two branches is _not_ indicative of what would happen if one branch were merged into the other. Basically it seems you don't know what a merge is at all. My article will tell you.

Comment: Finally (sorry to rattle on, this is the last one) it is not clear what your goal is. If it is to make the two branches identical, well, you've already shown that you know how to do that. But that is not what a merge does, and it is not what a merge is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that happened here is perfectly logical if you understand what git is trying to achieve.

Rather than switching back and forward between branches with abstract names, imagine you have two developers, Alice and Bob, each working on a branch with their name.

Over time Alice's code had drifted from Bob's, so on branch `Alice` she ran:

```
git reset --hard Bob
```

After this when she ran `git diff Bob` no differences were shown by git, because the two branches pointed at exactly the same commit. Let's imagine theirs a third branch pointing at this, called "agreed-base".

Now, Alice changed one file in her branch - pom.xml

Now, when she runs `git diff Bob` she will see the change she has made, which has not been made on Bob's branch. If Bob, with his branch checked out, runs `git diff Alice`, he will also see this change - regardless of whose change it was, it is currently a difference between the two branches.

If instead both developers ran `git diff agreed-base`, Alice would see her change, but Bob would see no changes, because his branch is still identical to that base.

Next, Bob changed some code (let's say IndexController.java) and committed the change on his branch. Now both pom.xml and IndexController.java are different between the two branches, so both Alice and Bob will see that if they use `git diff`.

Now if Bob runs `git diff agreed-base`, he'll see his change to IndexConteoller.java, but not Alice's; and if Alice runs that, she'll still see only her change to pom.xml.

Finally, the part that seemed to confuse you: Alice runs `git merge -X theirs Bob`. This looks for all the changes that Bob has made, and applies them on top of Alice's code. One way to look at this is that the merge command is looking at the difference between `agreed-base` and `Bob`.

Bob hasn't changed pom.xml, so nothing happens to that file; he has changed IndexController.java, so that file gets merged. If Alice had also changed that file, the `-X theirs` option would discard her changes, but since she hasn't, it has no effect.

Now when Alice runs `git diff Bob`, she sees the change to pom.xml, which she made and Bob doesn't have; she no longer sees the change to IndexController.java, because that is the same in both branches. If she runs `git diff agreed-base`, she will see *both* changes, because her branch now contains new versions of both pom.xml and IndexController.java

Answer (score 0):

The `tip` branch doesn't contain any commit that changed the `pom.xml` file. Thus when merging it into `master` branch, there's no reason for this file to be modified.

If you want `master` to have the exact same content as `tip`, you already know the answer as you did it: use `git reset --hard tip`.

Edit: maybe the confusion lies in the fact that merging in Git is about merging commits, not merging all the files content.